# Session expired on CTRL+F5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am using membership provide and login code is like:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        bool b = Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                Session["Role"] = Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName)[0];
                Session["UserName"] = true;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
                return RedirectToAction("TransHome", "Transcription");
            }
            else
                ViewBag.errmsg = "The user name or password is incorrect.";
            return View(model);
        }
```

Everytime on click of CTRL+F5 session is expired..any solution?

Comment: What are your sessionState configuration settings?

Comment: @dbugger <sessionState customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" mode="InProc" sqlCommandTimeout="30"  timeout="30">

Comment: Looks you have the kitchen sink in there.  Are you using inProc sessions, a custom provider, or sql server?

Comment: I am using inProc..I have to write only `<sessionState  mode="InProc"  timeout="30">` right?? @dbugger

Comment: and sqlConnectionString="" is also not needed..m i right?? @dbugger